# How do you implement IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, interface, ienumerable

I'm tearing my hair out. Apparently you can't just do something like

```
class Ranch<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
   // Mad code
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Hectic implementation details
    }
   // More mad code
}
```

I've searched the internet and I can't find a **simple** example of how to implement the damn thing ANYWHERE. Even MSDN. It's ridiculous.

Key word there being simple. I've found many a link which claims to tell me how to do it and then rambles on and on, bringing heaps of unnecessary and annoying other tidbits in. I want a simple "smack it down and run" code sample which is similar in size and scope to the psuedo-code above.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's exactly what it is. Except you replace the comments with actual mad code.

Comment: The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) have examples built right in.

Comment: What do you mean you can't do that?  What error are you getting?  (admitedly, it should be either public or explicit, and you'll also need to implement the non-generic version)  In any case, there are a *ton* of examples in the framework source.  (`System.Linq.Enumerable` alone has quite a lot)

Comment: http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/08/implementing-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-on-your-custom-objects/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9768/IInterfaces-Part-1-Implementing-IEnumerable-and-IE

Comment: You have searched the internet? And you haven't found anything? Weird. What keywords did you use for your search?

Comment: that link is useless. I've been there, read the wall of text, and it hasn't helped. I just want to be able to smack down a quick method implementation and move on. Surely there's a way to do it which is that simple. (sorry about the blunt/harsh wording, I've been getting progressively more pissed for the past 4 hours trying to work this out)

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle, please be more specific about what errors you are getting.  Your question is really bad as it stands.

Comment: You might be better served using List<T> as the base instead of IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface you also have to implement the `IEnumerable` interface that it inherits.

Right click on the interface in the class signature, and select *Implement Interface*, and you get a skeleton added at the end of the class:

```
class Ranch<T> : IEnumerable<T> {

  ...

  #region IEnumerable<T> Members

  public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  #endregion

  #region IEnumerable Members

  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

  #endregion
}
```

The `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` method can be implemented by just calling the `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` method:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
  return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I've been looking for something like that for ages! That's exactly what I want. All the other links I've found have been overcomplicated crap that bring heaps of other stuff into it which I don't care about. This is PERFECT.

Comment: How is that perfect? Once you try enumerate it, you'll get an exception... Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Of course not. It's a framework which type checks and compiles. I can finally work with that.

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle: The `yield` keyword makes implementing an enumerable trivial.  Look into that.

Comment: I'm aware. All I really wanted to say the whole time, was return new List<T> { Data }.Concat(SubTrees.SelectMany<ITree<T>,T>(x => (IEnumerable<T>)x.GetEnumerator())).GetEnumerator(); // Can't believe it took 4 hours to get it past the type checker

Comment: @YoryeNathan: It's a skeleton, as I said in the answer. The exception call is a placeholder for where you put your implemention.

Comment: @Guffa I see. I thought he wanted help implementing the enumerator itself.

Answer (score 3):

The interface `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable` and hides the method `GetEnumerator`. Copied from .net source:

```
  public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
  {
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(); // hides IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  }
```

You need to explicitly implement the non generic interface method `IEnumerable GetEnumerator()` as well:

```
class Ranch<T>: IEnumerable<T>
{
    // Mad code
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Hectic implementation details
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }

   // More mad code
}
```

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle: IEnumerable<T> inherits from IEnumerable ...

Comment: @TheIronKnuckle: The method `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` returns `IEnumerator<T>`, while the method `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` returns `IEnumerator`. Although it's common for the two `GetEnumerator()` methods to behave identically and return an object which implements both the generic `IEnumerator` and non-generic `IEnumerator`, there's no way the compiler can know that object returned by `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` will implement non-generic `IEnumerator`, nor that the one returned by `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` will implement `IEnumerator<T>`. Thus separate methods are needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Ranch<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
   // Mad code
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; ++i)
            yield return default(T);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
   // More mad code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation for ienumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) shows you can implement your own Enum for your custom class. Or to overwrite the `GetEnumerator()` method itself you can look at [the documentation for iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zzykke.aspx).

Example code for implementing method:

```
public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (object obj in underLyingCollection)
    {
        yield return obj;
    }
}
```

As others have stated you have to implement the generic (above) method as well.

Answer (score 1):

An example where `Mad Code` is a `List<T>`.  Once you create the class and specify that it inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, you can click on it and a drop down will appear saying `Options to implement interface`.  Click it and then select `Implement interface 'IEnumerable<T>'` and it will generate the necessary stubs.  Then you just fill in the mad code.

```
class Ranch<T>: IEnumerable<T> // <-- click here in VS
{
    List<T> _madCode = new List<T>(); // Mad code

    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _madCode.GetEnumerator(); // Hectic implementation details
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }

   // More mad code
}
```